# actionpoller interval param will not use controller property?

Tags: platform-bug, actionpoller

I have a VF page that presents a wizard.  Step 3 is a progress bar that periodically checks the status of a batch of requests sent off during step 2:

```
<apex:pageBlock rendered="{!step == 3}" title="Generating Previews">
  <p> refreshDelaySeconds: {!refreshDelaySeconds}</p>
  <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="meter" id="previewMeter">
    <span style="width: {!previewPercentDone}%"></span>
  </apex:outputPanel>
  <apex:actionPoller action="{!updatePreviewPercent}" rerender="previewMeter" 
                     interval="{!refreshDelaySeconds}" />
</apex:pageBlock>
```

The `<p>` showing refreshDelaySeconds is a debugging aid, to prove that the controller property `refreshDelaySeconds` being used as the `actionPoller`'s `interval` value is in fact populated.  Here's how `refreshDelaySeconds` is defined in the controller:

```
public static final integer REFRESH_DELAY_SECONDS = 5;
public integer refreshDelaySeconds {
    get { return REFRESH_DELAY_SECONDS; }
}
```

So the value must be 5 seconds, and the debugging output in the page confirms that the VF page is seeing a value of 5 seconds.  However, this page does not refresh until 60 seconds have passed - the default when no `interval`is specified.

Further, if I set the `interval` value to a literal, e.g.:

```
  <apex:actionPoller action="{!updatePreviewPercent}" rerender="previewMeter" 
                     interval="5" />
```

The page refreshes every 5 seconds, as it should.  So everything works as it should, as long as `interval` is a constant, but if I change it to a controller property, which I can prove holds the correct value, it does not refresh.

Is this a bug?  Known issue (searched and could not locate)?  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Quick Google: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000099BZIAY.

Comment: I think you should probably raise a case with support. In the meantime, you could probably just use `apex:actionFunction` with a regular old `setInterval` script, like so: `setInterval(updatePreviewPercent, {!refreshDelaySeconds*1000})`.